# Abstracting logic in Backbone js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, marionette

I'm developing a `Backbone` application using `Marionette` and I need some help to organize the logic in the code.

Currently I have a few views where I handle really similar logic, I want to abstract this to avoid repetition:

*View1*

```
onRender: function() {
    var pluginData = this.$("selector1").plugin();
    var pluginResult = this.handlePluginData(pluginData);
    this.doSomethingWithResult1(pluginResult);
}
```

*View2*

```
onRender: function() {
    var pluginData = this.$("selector2").plugin();
    var pluginResult = this.handlePluginData(pluginData);
    this.doSomethingWithResult2(pluginResult);
}
```

*Etc*

Note: `handlePluginData` do the same thing, `doSomethingWithResultN` it's different but can be abstracted with a few params.

So the questions are:

- How should I abstract this?, I thought of extending from a `BaseView` class and adding the logic there, but I don't know if there's a better way.
- It's okay to add a custom `Model` class which handles the calculation?. I've been using `rails` for a while and I'm used to Model === Table in database.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This seems like it might be a better question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hum, you might be right but, I know I want to abstract that code, what I'm asking is how to do it in Backbone in particular, and if using a model without a "table" it's okay.

Comment: Backbone or not, when your question is "I have this code; how do I change it" that's code review. For your second question, "is it ok to..." usually means it's opinion-based. Can you add a model? Of course you can! Should you? I have no idea. If that "model" is just running calculations on _other_ models, it sounds like you'd be better off with a helper class (which is like a model, but not a `Backbone` model.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Backbone View class is abstract enough. All you have to do is to pass different options when you create new View instance.

And I found that you place the calculating logic in View's render method. Because Backbone is a MVC-based framework, so logic should place in Model and View register event handler which is responsible for rendering layout when Model fire event which view is interested.

In my opinion, you could add a Model which handle calculate and redefine your view.

My simple example:

1.Define a model which is respond for logic calculating:

```
var MathModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    result: 0,
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("calculate target: "+this.get("selector"));
        console.log("calculate method: "+this.get("method"));
        var number = this.handlePluginData();
        this.doSomethingWithResult(number);
    },
    handlePluginData: function(){
        return $(this.get("selector")).text();
    },
    doSomethingWithResult: function(number){
        if(this.get("method")==="square"){
            this.set({result:(number*number)});
        }else{
            this.set({result:(number*number*number)});
        }

    }
});
```

2.Redefine the View class:

View will register a listener for model "result" data change event and render a initial layout according to the model you assigned.

```
var AbstractView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.listenTo(this.model,"change",this.onModelChange);
            this.number = this.model.get("result");
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(this.number); 
        },
        onModelChange: function(model){
            this.number = model.get("result");
            this.render();
        },
        plusOne:function(){
            this.model.doSomethingWithResult(this.model.handlePluginData());
        }
    });
```

3.Pass different options to model when you instantiate a new View.

```
var view1 = new AbstractView({el:"#result1",model:new MathModel({selector:".square",method:"square"})});
var view2 = new AbstractView({el:"#result2",model:new MathModel({selector:".cubic",method:"cubic"})});
```

4.HTML:

```
<div id="select-target">
    <span class="square">2</span>
    <span class="cubic">2</span>
    <button id="plus-one">+1</button>
</div>
<div id="result">
    <span id="result1"></span>
    <span id="result2"></span>
</div>
```

5.Plus-one button click event handler:

You could observe how View re-render it's layout when model is changed.

```
$("#plus-one").click(function(){
        $(".square").text(Number($(".square").text())+1);
        $(".cubic").text(Number($(".cubic").text())+1);
        view1.plusOne();
        view2.plusOne();
    });
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: It helps, thank you!. I'm still not conviced with `MathModel = Backbone.Model.extend` I think I'm going to use a custom class and instantiate that.